# In Haskell, how to fmap between distinct Traversables?

Tags: haskell, traversal, functor

As we know, `fmap`'s signature is `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` where `f` is a `Functor`.

It seems natural that to be as general as possible, and factor code better, one might want to map a "list of things" to another possibly distinct "list of things". Intuitively I do not see why it should not be possible, or not desirable.

What I'm looking for is a function `gmap` with same behavior as `fmap` but with that signature `gmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a) -> (g b)` where I'm allowing arrival and departure containers to differ.

I am not sure if this would make sense in the very general case where `f` and `g` are `Functors`, however the idea of a "list of things" sounds more essentially captured by the `Traversable` class, assuming I'm mostly interested in iterating over data.

So perhaps the signature should be `gmap :: (Traversable f, Traversable g) => (a -> b) -> (f a) -> (g b)`.

Even if `g` is of different nature as `f`, it's still something one can traverse from left to right, so it still feels like one should be able to map the k-th visited element of `f` to the k-th visited element of `g`.

Assuming my thinking didn't go wrong,  is there such a function in Haskell?

Essentially, my question, is how would you convert from one list-like thing to another in Haskell, in the most factored and elegant way?

Comment: How would you turn a list into a tree? Both are traversables. Even if a tree is traversable left-to-right, knowing its traversal does not allow to reconstruct the tree in a unique way. We could generate "a tree" but that would require a pretty much arbitrary choice. Classes like foldable/traversable inherently describe ways to _consume_ containers, rather than _producing_ them. Perhaps you want another class.

Comment: @chi Yes it might not be the right class, then i would be looking for the most general one for that purpose.

Comment: Assuming such a class existed, would it support only list-like containers? Can you imagine any other container that can be creates from a list in a meaningful way?

Comment: Perhaps, I would want to convert a list to a vector, but somehow I don't want to write specific code to convert a list to a vector. I would like to find what is the most factored, most general most beautiful way to convert between two list-like things.

Comment: Not possible in general. Consider `x :: NonEmpty Void` `x = gmap id []`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't this look like the composition of `fmap` and a natural transformation between functors..?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yeah I thought of natural transformations, somehow what I want is mapping a functor to another functor.. but I'm not really an expert with Haskell..

Comment: `Yeah I thought of natural transformations, somehow what I want is mapping a functor to another functor..` - while I'm not very familiar with natural transformations in Haskell, in mathematics that ("a mapping from a functor to another functor") is *precisely* what a natural transformation is.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes like you, I was referring to the mathematical meaning. I do not know how to express natural transformations in Haskell either, but I think that is what I'm trying to do here. I see there are some libraries, I might check them out later. I think JosephSible's counter example shows that I need additional requirements that might be formalized by those natural transformations things.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the (horizontal?) composition of two natural isomorphisms. That is, something is "list-like" if there is a natural isomorphism between that thing and `[]`. If `a ~> []` and `b ~> []` are both isomorphisms, then it is trivial to define `a ~> b` and `b ~> a` by going through `[]` in either direction. (Where `type f ~> g = forall x. f x -> g x` is a natural transformation.)

Comment: (The isomorphism is important, because while you can define both `[] ~> Maybe` and `Maybe ~> []`, it's not an isomorphism because going from a list to a `Maybe` will lose all but one element of the original list, so you can't get the original list back given only its `Maybe` counterpart.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick we often use in Haskell to show that things are not possible is trying to produce "false" with it -- aka, produce a value of type

```
data Void
```

the type with no constructors.  If it is possible, using your type signature, to produce a value of type `Void`, then your type signature is not possible to be implemented.  This is also known as "reducto ad absurdum", or "disproof by contradiction".  If your type signature would allow us to produce a value of type `Void`...then "obviously" your type signature is bunk and cannot be implemented.

In this case we are "returning" a `Traversable` instance, so let's use a `Traversable` like `(,) Void`:

```
instance Traversable ((,) w) where
    traverse f (x, y) = (x,) <$> f y
```

Now let's use `f` as any old functor.  It could be anything...let's use `Maybe` because it seems like everyone already understands it.

Then, you could write:

```
gmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> (Void, b)
```

Oh no, that can't be right ... it looks like using gmap you can create a `Void` just by passing in any old thing:

```
gmap :: (() -> ()) -> Maybe () -> (Void, ())
```

So now my strategy for creating `Void`:

```
bad :: Void
bad = fst (gmap id Nothing)
```

Because `Void` has no constructors, a value of type `bad :: Void` shoudn't exist (disregarding something like an infinite loop or partial function).  So, if the mere existence if `gmap` can allow us to create a value of type `Void`...it must mean that `gmap` cannot exist in the form you gave.

---

For your more general problem, the "why" in how `Traversable` works is that it can only ever *modify* structures.  It cannot *create* them.  Here, you want to create a value of `g b`, but `Traversable` cannot "create" it, it can only "transform" it.  Your misunderstanding might be coming from you thinking that `Traversable` is a "list-like" typeclass: it's not, quite.  Using `[]` as a archetype might be leading you astray.

My "typical" `Traversable` to imagine properties of the typeclass for is `Map k`, from *containers*'s `Data.Map`: a `Map` isn't a, but rather values associated with keys.  Any operations on it would have to be able to respect this association property...and not treat it as a big list with no extra structure.

So what *would* be possible is something like:

```
replace :: (Foldable f, Traversable g) => f a -> g b -> g a
```

Where all of the values of the `g b` are replaced by all the values of the `f a`.  This one is actually sort of fun to write, if you are looking for an exercise.  Basically, `replace` would *keep* the same **structure** that the `g a` had, but just *replace* the **values**.  So you can "create" a `g a` from an `f a` as long as you had an "example `g b`", so to speak.  If you used something like:

```
replace :: [a] -> Map k b -> Map k a
```

then `replace` would replace all the values in the second map with the items in the list, replacing them at the proper key values.

Then you can write:

```
gmap :: (Traversable a, Traversable g) => (a -> b) -> f a -> g c -> g b
```

Where you take an "example" `g a` of the structure you want to copy.

The closest thing to being able to "construct" a structure in Haskell's common typeclasses is `IsList`, from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList

This typeclass gives you two functions, `fromList` and `toList`, so you could write:

```
throughIsList :: (IsList l, IsList m, Item l ~ Item m) => l -> m
throughIsList = fromList . toList
```

And making it work over `Functor`s:

```
gmap :: (IsList (f a), IsList (g b), Item (f a) ~ a, Item (g b) ~ b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> g b
gmap f = fromList . map f . toList
```

The problem is now that most `Functor`s are not instances of `IsList`...and many of the actual instances aren't total.  So it's not quite usable for most `Functor`s.

---

So in the end I don't think there is any satisfying answer.  If something you were doing relies on the fact that there is a good answer (other than an answer of "no")...maybe can I ask what your "final goal" is?  What are you planning on using this type for?

(For example, in 90% of situations where people ask questions like "is there a way I can convert monads" or something like that, usually they *don't* want to do something in *general*, but rather they had *specific* types they had in mind.)

Comment: Nice answer. I think the signature for `replace` is not quite general enough: `replace :: (...) => f a -> g b -> g a`.  Or `g ()` if we really want to make it clear that we are just using its shape.

Comment: @Justin
No I'm not trying to achieve something specific. I feel my question is drifting away from what I really wanted to know. Perhaps Traversable is not the good fit here, i dont want ppl to focus on it then.
There are different kinds of lists, for example vectors, arrays, lists. Im wondering what is the common denominator to these structures. What do they have in common that make them "list-like" ?? Is there a Haskell type that expresses this?, if so could this general "list-like" type be used to convert between different "list-like" types?

Comment: I should repost a question. I think there are probably no list-like types anyway.. its too specific to be part of base. Anyway using this replace function seems good enough

Comment: @J.M. If you're looking for what units vectors, arrays, lists, etc., then `IsList` might be a start.  But a more principled approach might be the *mono-traversable* library, which has typeclasses for various types of "containers" of varying degrees of specificity/functionality.

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own type class, and a way to go from one functor to another, this is one example of one way to convert list to Tree, but you can use whatever you consider correct to fit your problem.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

class (Functor f, Functor g) => GFunctor f g where
  toG :: f a -> g a
  gmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a) -> (g b)
  gmap fn functor = toG $ fmap fn functor

data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show

instance Functor Tree where
  fmap f Leaf = Leaf
  fmap f (Node t1 x t2) = Node (fmap f t1) (f x) (fmap f t2)

instance GFunctor [] Tree  where
  toG [] = Leaf 
  toG [x] = Node Leaf x Leaf
  toG (x:xs) = Node (toG $ (takeHalf xs)) x ((toG $ dropHald xs))

takeHalf xs = take ((length xs) `div` 2) xs
dropHald xs = drop ((length xs) `div` 2) xs

res :: Tree Int
res = gmap (+1) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

output:

```
   res
=> Node (Node Leaf 3 (Node Leaf 4 Leaf)) 2 (Node Leaf 5 (Node Leaf 6 Leaf))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can do this with `fmap` and a natural transformation. Here's an example using the [natural-transformations](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/natural-transformation) package, just to demonstrate the idea.

The first natural transformation that comes into my mind is `safeHead`:

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead [] = Nothing
safeHead (x:_) = Just x
```

Running GHCi with the `natural-transformations` package:

```
Prelude Control.Natural> t = wrapNT safeHead
Prelude Control.Natural> t # [1..3]
Just 1
Prelude Control.Natural> t # []
Nothing
Prelude Control.Natural> fmap show (t # [1..3])
Just "1"
Prelude Control.Natural> fmap show (t # [])
Nothing
```

So, for a natural transformation `t`, would something like `fmap f . (t #)` do what you want?

(Here, I'm imagining that `f` is a normal function `a -> b`.)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it appears that the asker is looking for a general version that works for *all* f and g, instead of specific f and g (like safeHead)